# A subadditive bijection on the positive reals

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

> **Question.** Does there exist a subadditive bijection $f$ of the positive reals $(0,\infty)$ such that
> $$
> \liminf_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0 \,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,\limsup_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=1\,?
> $$

Ps1. I guess the answer is no. However, it is affirmative if we replace "bijective" by "injective" by the following example: $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational, otherwise $f(x)=x+1$.

Ps2. The answer is also affirmative if we replace $$\limsup_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=1$$ with $$\limsup_{x\to 0^+}f(x)\neq 0.$$ Indeed, let $(x_i: i \in I)$ be an Hamel basis of the vector space $\mathbf{R}$ over $\mathbf{Q}$. Fix a nontrivial permutation $\sigma$ of $I$. For each $r=\sum_j \lambda_jx_j>0$ define $f(r)=|g(r)|$, where $g(r)=\sum_j \lambda_j x_{\sigma(j)}$ (*thanks i707107*). Note that $g$ is an additive bijection, hence
$$
f(x+y)=|g(x)+g(y)| \le f(x)+f(y)$$ for all $x,y>0$, so $f$ is subadditive. Now suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ with $x,y>0$. Then either $g(x)=g(y)$ so $x=y$, or $g(x)=-g(y)$ so each coefficient of $\lambda_j$ (in $x$) is the inverse of the corresponding (in $y$), so $x=-y$: if $x,y>0$, then $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ so $f$ is injective.

About surjectivity, fix $x=\sum_{j} \lambda_j x_j$ and define $y=\sum_j \lambda_j x_{\sigma^{-1}(j)}$. Hence $z:=\max(y,-y)>0$ and $f(z)=x$; so $f$ is subjective.

Finally, it is known that $g$ has a graph dense in $\mathbf{R}^2$, from which it holds also $\liminf_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$ and $\limsup_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: I realized the example is wrong. However, I write it since I don't know if it can be fixed: let $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ be an Hamel basis of $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Q}$ and let $\sigma$ be a nontrivial permutation of $I$. Then, if $r>0$ has representation as finite sum $\sum_j \lambda_jx_j$, we define the *additive* function $h(r)=\sum_j |\sigma(\lambda_j)|x_j$. However, I realized now that, although $h(r)>0$ for each $r$, the function is neither injective not surijective. (I remove that comment.)

Comment: What if $h(r)=|\sum_j \lambda_j x_{\sigma(j)}|$ ?

Comment: I think the above one is subadditive bijection with $\liminf_{x\rightarrow 0+} h(x)=0$, and $\limsup_{x\rightarrow 0+} h(x)=\infty$.

Comment: You are correct. I added the details in the OP

Comment: Thank you for putting the details. Those in PS2 are correct.

Comment: According to this paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2159841?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents The answer is affirmative if $\liminf_{x\rightarrow 0+} f(x) >0$.

Comment: @Noah Schweber Sorry. I have just suppressed the comment and sent it to the right person.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Your function f seems to be bounded, isn’t it?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that we want $f$ to map $(0,\infty)$ onto $(0,\infty)$... So I will delete my useless comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using ideas described in [Gowers blog post about Zorn's Lemma](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2008/08/12/how-to-use-zorns-lemma/) we will define a subadditive function $f\colon ℝ_+ → ℝ_+$ with the desired property.

Let $\mathcal{B} = \{e_β\}_{β ∈ B}$  be a Hamel Basis of $ℝ$ over the field of rationals. Since $\mathcal{B}$ remains a Hamel Basis when we replace $e_β$ with  $q\cdot e_β$ where $q$ is non-zero rational, we can assume that all $e_β > 0$ and there is $\{ e_n \}_{n \in ℤ_+} \subset \mathcal{B}$ such that $2^{-(n+1)}< e_n<2^{-n}$.

For each $n \in ℤ_+$ pick $a_n,b_n \in \mathbb{Q}_+$ such that $1 - 2^{-n} < a_n e_n <  b_n e_n  < 1$. Note $a_n e_n → 1$. Let $\text{span}(e_n) = \{ q e_n \mid q \in \mathbb{Q}_+\}$ and define a piecewise linear function $f_n \colon \text{span}(e_n) \to \text{span}(e_n)$ passing thru there points $(0,0), (e_n, a_n e_n)$ and $(b_n e_n, b_n e_n)$:
$$
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 a_n x, & 0 < x ≤ e_n,\\
 \frac{b_n-a_n}{b_n-1}x + e_n \frac{b_n(a_n-1)}{b_n-1}, & e_n < x ≤ b_n e_n,\\
 x, & b_n e_n < x.
\end{cases}
$$
(Pedantical note: Point $(0,0)$ does not belong to the graph of $f_n$, but this framing makes the idea behind $f_n$ clear.) To familiarize with $f_n$'s here is graph of $f_3$:

[image: f3]

Just keep in mind that domain and codomain are not $ℝ_+$ but $\text{span}(e_3)$.

Note that $f_n$ is well-defined since we always multiply $e_n$ by some positive rational, so the codomain is indeed $\text{span}(e_n)$. It's a bijection. Moreover, $f_n$ is subadditive. We verify this by boring casework at the end of this proof, but the upshot is this: In each case, we either use the fact that $f_n|_{(0,b_ne_n]}$ is concave and positive and hence subadditive, or that the graph of $f_n$ is above the identity, that is $x \leq f_n(x)$.

Finally, we can define $f\colon ℝ_+ → ℝ_+$ as
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 f_n(x), & x \in \text{span}(e_n),\\
 x, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
This is a well-defined function because each $x \in ℝ_+$ has a unique representation in terms of Hamel Base $\mathcal{B}$.

Function $f$ is a bijection. Clearly, $\liminf_{x → 0_+} f(x) = 0$ since it acts like the identity function for almost all inputs, and otherwise $f_n ≥ 0$. To find $\limsup$, first note that on $(0, 1]$, $f$ is bounded from above by $1$. Secondly, $e_n → 0$ and $1>f(e_n) > a_n e_n > 1-2^{-n}$, so $f(e_n) \to 1$. Hence, $\limsup_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = 1$ as required.

It remains to show that $f$ is subadditive. Take any $x,y \in ℝ_+$.

- If $x,y \in \text{span}(e_n)$ for some $n$. Then $x+y \in \text{span}(e_n)$ and subaddivity of $f$ follows from the subadditivity of $f_n$.
- If $x \in \text{span}(e_n)$ for some $n$ but $y \not\in \text{span}(e_n)$ (or vice versa). Then $f(x+y) = x+y$. Because $f_n(x) ≥ x$ as well as $f(y) ≥ y$ we have $f(x) + f(y) = f_n(x) + f(y) ≥ x + y = f(x+y)$.
- If none of the above cases are true, then $f(x+y) = x+ y = f(x) + f(y)$.

---

We show that the function $f_n$ is subadditive. Take $x,y \in \text{span}(e_n)$. WLOG assume that $x \leq y$. If $x,y$ and $x+y$ are in one of three intervals $(0, e_n]$, $[e_n, b_n e_n]$, or $[b_n e_n, \infty)$, then the condition holds, since a restriction of $f_n$ to each of those intervals is additive. It remains to show what happens in "mixed" cases.

When $x,y≤ e_n$ and:

- (A1) $e_n < x+y ≤b_n e_n$.
- (A2) $b_n e_n < x+y$.

When $x≤e_n<y$ and:

- (B1) $y,x+y ≤ b_ne_n$.
- (B2) $y≤ b_ne_n < x+y$.
- (B3) $b_ne_n < y, x+y$.

When (C) $e_n < x,y ≤ b_n e_n < x+y$.

When (D) $e_n < x <b_n e_n< y, x+y$.

Note that $f_n|_{(0, b_ne_n]}$ is concave and positive. Hence subadditive. Thus subadditivity for cases A1 and B1 is proven. Now assume A2 holds. Then
$$
f_n(x+y) = x+ y ≤ f_n(x)+f_n(y),
$$
since $f_n$ is on or above identity. The same reasoning will work for the rest of the cases.

□